# Как работает переадресация?

Tags: nginx

Есть сайт 1 который запрашивает картинку с сайта 2, который делает переадресацию для этой картинки и берет её с сайта 3. В итоге будет ли сайт 2 ждать ответ от сайта 3, чтоб отдать его сайту 1 или сайт 1 сам заберет её с сайта 3?

Хочу сделать так, чтоб при обращении стороннего сайта 1 за файлом к моему сайту, мой сайт 2 отправлял его на другой сайт 3 за файлом. т.е. мой сайт не должен участвовать в приеме байтов файла с другого сайта 3, чтоб отдать его сайту 1.

Comment: Зависит от настроек сервера.

Comment: @Qwerty, от каких настроек сервера?

Comment: От способа, которым выполняется переадресация. Точнее, выполняется ли она вообще.

Comment: @Querty можно пример?

Comment: Я думаю это вы должны предоставить пример, как у вас это реализовано, чтобы получить ответ. Либо переформулировать вопрос: хочу так, как сделать ...

Comment: @Total Publisher дополнил

Comment: ответ: используйте 301 редирект подойдет?

Comment: @Total Pusher return или rewrite или какой еще может быть вариант отдать ссылку не файл? редирект буду использовать 302

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу сделать так, чтоб при обращении стороннего сайта 1 за файлом к моему сайту, мой сайт 2 отправлял его на другой сайт 3 за файлом. т.е. мой сайт не должен участвовать в приеме байтов файла с другого сайта 3, чтоб отдать его сайту 1.

Делается через редирект. Сервер отдаст только новые заголовки и небольшую заглушку, а браузер перейдет по новому адресу сам.

В примере будет 302 редирект с каталога `/assets/` на аналогичный адрес сайта `site.ru`, но без префикса `/assets/`, например `http://localhost:8109/assets/images/blank.gif` => `http://site.ru/images/blank.gif`

```
server {
  listen 8109;
  location /assets/ {
    rewrite ^/assets/(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 break;
    return 302;
  }
}
```

[Мана](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)